# return multiple json results

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have to output `$var1`. To do that, I return results by using

```
sendJson($var1);
```

And this is working fine for me. Now I want to pass two variables `$var1` and `$var2` using  `sendJson();`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put them all inside an array:

```
sendJson(array($var1, $var2));
```

Or name them if you don't want to do it index-based:

```
sendJson(array('var1' => $var1, 'var2' => $var2))
```

Comment: How i can i retrieve these values in ajax success function

Comment: You can do it index based with `json[0]` and `json[1]` or you can assign a name to the arrays with `sendJson(array('var1' => $var1, 'var2' => $var2))`

Answer (score 4):

name your array keys:

```
echo json_encode( array (
    'messages' => array(
        'peter' => 'Hello',
        'john'  => 'Hi to you too'
    ),
    'users'     => array (
        'peter', 'john'
    )
));
```

and then access them like this:

```
resp.messages.peter
resp.messages.john
```

or

resp.users[0], resp.users[1].... etc.